# How to return out of command pattern in controller so that application stops running (Java)?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am designing a controller using the command pattern.
The controller has a while loop inside that is scanning for user input. If user input matches a specific String, then a command class is executed. Here is a code snippit:

```java
  public Controller(Readable in, Appendable out) {
    this.out = out;
    this.scan = new Scanner(in);
    this.commandMap = this.generateCommands();
  }

public void go(Model m) {

      while (scan.hasNext()) {
        
        String input = scan.next();
        Command command = this.commandMap.get(input);
          command.do(m);
        }
}
```

I usually use `return` to stop the application. However, when I use `return` inside one of the Command classes, the application keeps running. I think it just goes back to this upper loop.
By the way, all my commands are `public void`.

**Is there a way to exit/close the application from within the command classes?** Like a "super" return? Or do I need to no longer make them `void` and if/else the return in the controller.

EDIT: `system.exit(0)` doesn't seem like the right solution for me because it doesn't preserve the appendable log? My JUnit tests no longer print out everything I have appended once system.exit(0) is called.

Comment: Please place entire controller class also class that has command pattern implemented. Can you please elaborate what you are intending to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to terminate the entire program:

```
System.exit(0);
```